# How to inherit from `LeafSystem<T>` in other pybind11 module

Tags: pybind11, drake

first of all, thanks for this great project!

I have the following situation: I'm developing a C++ library which uses `drake` as a dependency. Specifically I have a custom System, inheriting from `LeafSystem<T>`:

```cpp
// my_system.h
#include <drake/systems/framework/leaf_system.h>

template <typename T>
class MySystem : public drake::systems::LeafSystem<T> {
 public:
  MySystem() {}
};
```

I want to expose this system also via a Python API, also using pybind11 like drake is doing, i.e.:

```cpp
// my_module.cpp
#include "my_system.h"
#include <drake/systems/framework/leaf_system.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m) {
  py::module::import("pydrake.systems.framework");
  py::class_<MySystem<double>, drake::systems::LeafSystem<double>>(m, "MySystem").def(py::init<>());
}
```

This compiles with CMake, life is good. But when I try to import `MySystem` in python, the base class cannot be resolved:

```py
>>> import my_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In [2], line 1
    import my_module
ImportError: generic_type: type "MySystem" referenced unknown base type "drake::systems::LeafSystem<double>"
```

I suspect it has something to do with the way drake generates the actual name of the binding, but this is all way beyond my head:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/72794d7818ef51629ed97faf6cd325004f49eb9a/bindings/pydrake/common/cpp_template_pybind.h#L90-L93

How can I create python bindings for my class which inherits from `drake::system::framework::LeafSystem` (or any other system, really)?

Thanks for your help!

The only relevant information I could find on `pybind11` is [from the officle docs about inheritance](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#inheritance-and-automatic-downcasting), which don't apply in my case, since the bindings of the base have already been written.

I tried to simulate the situation by compiling a `libfoo.so` which exports one base class `Foo` and its bindings. If `MySystem` inherits from `Foo` I can get the python binding to work just fine:

```cpp
// Simulated foo library and its bindings
class Foo {};

#include "foo.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m) {
  m.doc() = "hello, foo";
  py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo").def(py::init<>());
}
```

In *another* lib, this now works:

```cpp
class MySystem : Foo {};

PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m) {
  py::class_<MySystem, Foo>(m, "MySystem").def(py::init<>());
}
```

Comment: Could you share exactly what revision of Drake you are using, and which installation method (built from source, apt, tar.gz, etc)?  The pydrake template naming convention changed just yesterday, so for us to repro it's important to be precise here.

Comment: I installed drake via `apt` on Ubuntu 20.04. `apt list drake-dev` yields `drake-dev/focal,now 1.12.0-1 amd64 [installed]`. For my lib I'm using a Clang 10.0.0 compiler & Python 3.8.10. Hope this helps

Comment: See [drake_cmake_installed](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/main/drake_cmake_installed) build system demonstration in the subdir `src/simple_bindings`.  That sounds like exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, that's very similar to my use case. Strangely, the `drake_cmake_installed` project faced the same issue on my machine. Turned out, the problem only occurs with `clang++`. With `g++` (<10) everything works as expected. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: Interesting!  Our [Installation](https://drake.mit.edu/installation.html) page remarks: _"If you are compiling your own C++ code against Drake’s C++ code and are using Drake’s pre-compiled binaries, then you must use the same compiler as our releases: GCC 9 (for 20.04)_". C++ ABI compatibility is a difficult beast; using the same compiler for all code is one way to help avoid the pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Does it fix it if you add `py::module::import("pydrake.systems.framework");` to your `PYBIND11_MODULE` before trying to define your class?

For any C++ classes used by a pybind11 binding that are from other modules, you need to `py::import` that module before you can inherit from it (or use it as an argument, or etc).

Comment: Unfortunately not =( Same error as above, that the base type `drake::systems::LeafSystem<double>` cannot be found.

Comment: Also one more thing, I noticed: In an `ipython` session I `from pydrake.systems.framework import LeafSystem` and did a `help(LeafSystem)`. The help shows infos for `LeafSystem_[float]` (with trailing underscore), not for `LeafSystem[float]`. Is there some type wrapping going on?

Comment: The `LeafSystem` is an alias for `LeafSystem_[float]`.  The LeafSystem is templated, with things like `LeafSystem_[AutoDiffXd]` also available.  See https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#scalar-types.